# How to use Bitcoind's getreceivedbyaddress function

Tags: php, bitcoin, bitcoind

I have the Bitcoin Core version v0.9.0.0-g92d25e4-beta (64-bit) software installed on my computer and the config file is also setted up, and Bitcoind running in background.
I have a small PHP script(run over localhost), this script communicate with bitcoind via RPCClient json.
I created 2 request payment in my Bitcoin  Core wallet and i sent the money to generated address from my blockchain BTC wallet, the money was sent successfully and it has 3 confirmations too.

Now, i would like to check the transactions status in php with Bitcoind's Getreveivedbyaddress('generated address here') function.I would like to now when the money is received.
I tried to call many times that function but it return always 0.(destination addresses are internal adresses becouse it were generated via BitCoin Core )

```
  print $bitcoind->getreceivedbyaddress('13hHHBcaccPM5XSSiihhbrzRChbyvP49QQ');
```

I am sorry for my English;

Comment: Do you own that address? Do you have error reporting enabled? If yes, then does it give any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the command in the console.

```
bitcoind getreceivedbyaddress bitcoinaddresshere
```

And see what is returned.

========

Have you initialised your connection with bitcoind in PHP?

========

Have you setup your bitcoin.conf file to allow RPC connections?

```
server=0

rpcuser=user

rpcpassword=password
```